# Происходит обращение к фрагменту раньше его создания

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, fragment-transaction

Имеется активити, в котором постоянно чередуются 2 фрагмента, после кода замены фрагмента, происходит код в котором наполняются view элементы этого фрагмента, но вылетает nullPointException, поскольку onCreateView в фрагменте еще не был вызван. 
В чем проблема, как мне синхронизировать эти действия ?

Все происходит тут, фрагмент еще не успевает появиться на экране, как происходит вызов метода setFocusPlayer, которой пытается заполнить view в фрагменте

```
private void setTalkScreen() {
    replaceFragment(playersTalkFragment);

    if (world.isPlayerInGame(0)) {
        setFocusPlayer(0);
    } else {
        setFocusPlayer(world.nextPlayer(World.NONE));
    }
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
    Log.d(LOGIC, "GameActivity -> replaceFragment");
}
```

Comment: Код. Покажите код. Вообще не понятно, что и когда Вы делаете.

Comment: @ RostislavDugin код добавил

Comment: И когда Вы вызываете этот код? От куда берете `fragmentManager`?

Comment: @ RostislavDugin FragmentManager сохраняю в onCreate, код вызывается после onResume, и потом несколько раз во время сессии

Comment: А на какой строчке вылетает NPE?

Comment: @RostislavDugin setFocusPlayer(), там происходит обращение к view элементу, который должен инициализироваться в onCreateView фрагмента, но onCreateView еще не успевает вызваться

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, Вы добавляете фрагмент, а потом меняете на какой-то его вьюшке фокус, но выскакивает ошибка из-за того, что у фрагмента еще не вызвался `onCreateView`, да?

Comment: @Rostislav верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в `Fragment` обратный вызов к `Activity` в метод `onAttach`:

```
class TheFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface ActivityCallback {
        void onAttach();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach() {
        ...
        ((ActivityCallback) activity).onAttach();
    }
}

class TheActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TheFragment.ActivityCallback {

    @Override
    onAttach() {
        //Делаете ваши действия с фрагментом,
        //он уже готов. К работе, я имею ввиду :)
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 0):

Я советую попробовать вам либо как @Rostislav, либо попробовать вместо `commit` использовать `commitNow`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло